# How can I resolve 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError X509CertReader error' when JDK8 to JDK17 upgrade?

Tags: x509certificate, x509

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oracle.pic.commons.client.https.X509CertReader (in unnamed module @0x74582ff6) cannot access class sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x74582ff6

**complete error logs**

```
2023-06-02 11:51:30.778 INFO 9 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-1] c.oracle.pic.vault.InternalVaultClient   : 202105 VaultJavaSdk: Going to refresh the certs now
2023-06-02 11:51:30.786 INFO 9 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-1] c.o.p.c.c.http.OracleHttpClientBuilder   : DynamicSslContextProviderConfig is not configured. Attempting to use tlsConfig
2023-06-02 11:51:30.861 INFO 9 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oracle.pic.commons.client.https.X509CertReader (in unnamed module @0x74582ff6) cannot access class sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x74582ff6] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oracle.pic.commons.client.https.X509CertReader (in unnamed module @0x74582ff6) cannot access class sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x74582ff6
        at com.oracle.pic.commons.client.https.X509CertReader.fromPem(X509CertReader.java:81)
        at com.oracle.pic.commons.client.https.X509CertReader.readCertificatesFromPem(X509CertReader.java:41)
        at com.oracle.pic.commons.client.http.auth.KeystoreGenerator.createTrustStoreWithServerCa(KeystoreGenerator.java:48)
        at com.oracle.pic.commons.client.http.auth.TlsConfigurator.configureClientTrustStore(TlsConfigurator.java:85)
        at com.oracle.pic.commons.client.http.auth.TlsConfigurator.customizeBuilder(TlsConfigurator.java:55)
        at
```

I have moved from JDK8 to JDK17 and facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

With JDK17, we need to pass certain security certificate exports and parameters. They are mentioned below :

`ADD_EXPORTS="--add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED"`

`D_ARGS="-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Dgraal.VectorizeSIMD=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/cacerts"`

Now executing the jar will not throw the error!

`java $D_ARGS $ADD_EXPORTS -jar $JAR`